# How to search and replace with sed in a line with variable content in it?

Tags: shell-script, sed

I tried to use sed to edit some part of a specific line in a text file and save the change to the original file. OK I now understand that this is not the way sed directly works.
But how can I use sed in a script to edit the part of a line with variable content in it?
I already used sed to change complete lines or used lines as trigger to cut and insert to a new file. But this is different :)
I think what I need is

```
sed '/baz/s/foo/bar/g'

sed '/beginning of line/s/static text/new static text/g'
```

This gives me the right output but how can I save it to the source file?
I understand that sed outputs to stoud but when I add a ">> outpufile" it gives me an error message

```
sed: -e Ausdruck #1, Zeichen 55: Unbekannte Option für `s'
```

Between static text and new static text is some content that changes from time to time so

```
sed -n '/static text/new static text/,$p' tmp >> source
```

will work only for as long as the source content hasn't changed.

Any suggestions?

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

```
micha@linux-micha: /tmp
$ echo 'alpha bravo charlie' > blah.txt

micha@linux-micha: /tmp
$ cat blah.txt
alpha bravo charlie

micha@linux-micha: /tmp
$ sed -i 's/bravo/delta/' blah.txt

micha@linux-micha: /tmp
$ cat blah.txt
alpha delta charlie
```

Comment: OK it's a bit late here... I'm confused ^^
Can you explain further please

Comment: Hi, thought you meant *in-place* editing a file using sed. That's possible with the `-i` or `--in_place` flag. See it in my 3rd command above? Regards.

Comment: Ok sry I had to work on another few things. So here's the thing.
But what if this certain string an a row exists in many other rows in that file? Then all bravo would be replaced with delta. How could I tell sed to only handle this certain row?
Example row:
abc blah texttochange def blah texttochange blahblah
ABC is a static fixed part that never changes so could be possibility for a sed trigger

Comment: Ok sry I had to work on another few things. So here's the thing.
But what if this certain string in a row exists in many other rows in that file? Then all bravo would be replaced with delta. How could I tell sed to only handle this certain row?
Example row:
# abc blah texttochange def blah texttochange blahblah #
ABC is a static fixed part that never changes so could be used as a trigger
DEF is some random variable text and changes from time to time.

Comment: Sry for the double but the 5 minute timer got me trapped :)

Comment: Sry guys again. Answered the question myself.
I do it like Micha mentioned above and luckily I have significant triggers around the text i want to change. So now i can replace text in a certain row but with dynamic changing words in it. Sometimes trail and errot is the best method. :)